# Can the expression $\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-r} {{n-r} \choose {i}}a^{r+i-1}b^{n-(r+i)}$ be further simplified?

Tags: combinatorics, closed-form

I am trying to teach myself about summations and techniques of simplifying a complicated expression. I was wondering if the following summation can be simplified, or maybe possibly re-written in a different form?

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-r} {{n-r} \choose {i}}a^{r+i-1}b^{n-(r+i)}$$

I have tried expanding the term ${{n-r}\choose i}$, but it has not gotten me to anything meaningful.

Comment: You could start by factoring out terms that do not depend on the summation index: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-r} {{n-r} \choose {i}}a^{r+i-1}b^{n-(r+i)} = a^{r-1}b^{n-r}\sum_{i=0}^{n-r} {{n-r} \choose {i}} \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^i$$

Comment: Thank you! this is helpful, I am going to work on your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-r} {{n-r} \choose {i}}a^{r+i-1}b^{n-(r+i)}&= \sum_{r=1}^{n}a^{r-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-r} {{n-r} \choose {i}}a^{i}b^{(n-r)-i)} \\
&= \sum_{r=1}^{n}a^{r-1}(a+b)^{n-r}\\
&= (a+b)^{n-1}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^{r-1}\\
&=(a+b)^{n-1}\dfrac{1-\left(\frac a{a+b}\right)^n}{1-\frac{a}{a+b}}\\
&=\frac{(a+b)^n-a^n}{b}
\end{align}$$